# What happens to idempotency when a Kafka producer is restarted or fails?

Tags: apache-kafka

It looks like deduplication is performed by the Kafka broker by tracking messages at the partition level by:

1. message sequence number
2. producer id

Everything I'm reading talks about this solving the problem of a producer or broker error that results in the producer retrying the send.  What about when the producer goes down?  Is the producer id a static id controlled by me or is it reassigned by the broker every time a producer node is registered?  If the producer id is reassigned and different than it was before it's restarted, that would be duplicates will happen, right?

I don't understand why that would be the way they designed producer id but I can't find any `PRODUCER_ID_CONFIG` in `org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig` so it looks to be the way it was designed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is duplication in this scenario.  I'm not sure why PID was designed to be transient rather than persisting between sessions, but from the [implemented proposal](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-98+-+Exactly+Once+Delivery+and+Transactional+Messaging#KIP-98-ExactlyOnceDeliveryandTransactionalMessaging-DataFlow):

> This ensures that, even though a producer must retry requests upon
>   failures, every message will be persisted in the log exactly once.
>   Further, since each new instance of a producer is assigned a new,
>   unique, PID, we can only guarantee idempotent production within a
>   single producer session.

Edit:  it looks like this problem is solved by TransacitonalId which *is* provided by me.  It's detailed in the same document linked above.